# How to set the value of a string field using a checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In a Rails app I have a model with a string attribute, that can only accept a short list of possible values.

A gender select is a good example of this:

```
(using simpleform)
<%= f.input :gender, :collection => [["male"],["female"]], :prompt => "Select" %>
```

and provides three states, 'male', 'female', and unselected.

In an effort to improve UX, we're replacing this select field with two checkboxes with values of 'male' and 'female', which again provides three options due to some jquery magic.

```
male / false
false / female
false / false
```

The problem is, the value of the first checkbox is alway overwritten by the value of the second on form submit.

Now I could do something with jquery on the client side to deal with this, I could also create a method on the server to deal with this. But that is not the purpose of this question.

I've never been confident that I fully understand all of the various features and uses of `f.check_box`, `check_box object` and `check_box_tag`. Is there a clever way to achieve the desired result within a Rails form, or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: A checkbox presumes that you're okay with a user selecting *both* options.  It feels like, from your initial design, that you want a radio button group instead; one for each option that you want to provide (male, female, or other).

Comment: Thanks at Makoto, I'd thought about using radios, but would prefer only the 2 controls